# Substance Painter 2 and GL_EXT_gpu_shader4

Tags: linux, graphics-card, opensuse, opengl

I am trying to run Substance Painter 2 (On OpenSUSE Tumbleweed), and it does work except for the not-so-little problem that the shaders don't compile.

Obviously you would suspect some or a combination of: graphics-card not supported,graphics drivers not up to date. As I interpret it from https://www.allegorithmic.com/products/tech-specs my card (intel graphics HD 5500) should be ok. And again it works except for the shader-compiling problem.

I do have the GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 extension, i.e:

```
glxinfo | grep GL_EXT_gpu_shader
GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range,
```

So it seems likely to me that it should satisfy the GL_EXT_gpu_shader4

Is it just my lack of understanding that is standing in the way here, I mean it doesn't list GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 explicitly and perhaps it's not a "5 is greater than 4 and therefor automatically satisfy..."

Comment: Note : Integrated GPUs are not recommended -- 
Note : Mesa drivers on Linux are not supported -- boths applies on Intel GPU